# How to create a palette with my colours and use it like "scale_fill_brewer"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, palette

I m trying to generate my own palette, which contains 30 colours. I want to have my palette and use it in the same way as " + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") is used because I want to automatically apply it to several variables in different graphs.

What I ve done is (aiming to use numbers to call colours latter on):

```
dp_colors <- c(
  `1`        = "#B8E9D9",
  `2`      = "#FCDEBE",
  `3`       = "#CDDBD4",
  `4`     = "#CDDDAC",
..`30`     = "#CDDBD4")
```

how to build a function where I can just add something like + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") for it to fill every possible colour in that order and automatically....? thanks!

Comment: `ggplot` has a built-in function for this: `discrete_scale`, [which is a constructor for discrete scales](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.0/topics/discrete_scale).  It's actually called with functions like `scale_fill_brewer` (which you can see if you type the function into your console without the parentheses.  I don't have experience using it, but I'd start there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I m gonna try it and will let u know!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "values" may solve the issue:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(as.factor(cyl), fill = as.factor(cyl))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      '4' = "red",
      '6' = "green",
      '8' = "black"))[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Sadly, I had already tried that and did not work. That's why I asked about how to build a function where I can just add something like  + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")  for it to fill every possible colour in that order and automatically